# Google Cloud Billing working with a Python API to get Sku_id billed details

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-billing

I'm working on a project to monitor my Google Billing though BigQuery queries with Python.

I succeed to collect the list of all services and sku billed with the following code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Initialize the BigQuery client
client = bigquery.Client()

# Query to retrieve the billing information
query = """
SELECT
  DISTINCT sku.id as sku_id,
  sku.description as sku_description
FROM `fr-gcp-im-billing.fr_gcp_im_billing.XXX`
ORDER BY 2
"""

# Make the query request
query_job = client.query(query)

# Fetch the results
results = query_job.result()

# Extract the sku names and sku IDs from the results
sku_info = [(row.sku_description, row.sku_id) for row in results]

# Generate a dictionary to collect sku_id as key and sku_description as value
sku_billed = {}
for sku_description, sku_id in sku_info:
    sku_billed[sku_id] = sku_description
```

Now with this dictionary containing all my Sku billed on the period, I would like to have more details like sku.category who contains 4 elements as

```
{
  "serviceDisplayName": string,
  "resourceFamily": string,
  "resourceGroup": string,
  "usageType": string
}
```

This to be found in the Google Method [services.skus.list](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list).

Any hint to use this method with a list of sku to retrieve details?